# Почему не срабатывает event.preventDefault(); в данном случае?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
validateForm.submit(function (event) {
            // Prevents Default
            event.preventDefault();

            // Logging form errors
            var falseCtn = 0;
            for (var i = 1; i <= validatingLength; i++) {
                if (validate['input' + i] == false) {
                    falseCtn++;
                }
            }

            // Checking if any falses exist
            if (falseCtn > 0) {
                $(this).unbind('submit').submit();
                $(this).click();
            } else {}
        });
```

Comment: вообще должно сработать, но зачем тут это? это для того что бы событие не всплыло.

Comment: @RazmikGalstyan нужно чтобы браузерное событие по умолчанию не работало, а только которое у меня настроено. Они оба срабатывают при наличии этого event.preventDefault();

Comment: через debugger смотрел, заходит ли вообще в этот метод?

Answer (score 1):

Вместо `event.preventDefault();` можешь так же написать `return false;` Так должно работать.

`e.preventDefault()` предотвратит появление события по умолчанию, `e.stopPropagation()` предотвратит появление пузырьков и `return false` сделает оба.

Answer (score 0):

Вместо event.preventDefault(); тут нужно [event.stopPropagation](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Event/stopPropagation)

preventDefault сбрасывает только дефолтное действие браузера (например переход по ссылке при клике, или отправка формы по кнопке).
А stopPropagation предотвратит дальнейшее всплытие евента

Comment: Вы наверное немного перепутали, вот описание всех методов
[тут](https://codeplanet.io/preventdefault-vs-stoppropagation-vs-stopimmediatepropagation/)

Comment: @KirillStaruhin **Event.preventDefault** will ensure that the form is never submitted, **but it won’t control or prevent that submit or click event from bubbling up**.  **stopPropagation ensures that the event doesn’t bubble any further.**   Что перепутал?

Comment: @Darth человек не в адеквате просто, бейте тревогу

Comment: @Darth Александр в своём втором комментарии под вопросом написал "нужно чтобы браузерное событие по умолчанию не работало, а только которое у меня настроено." . Действие по умолчанию у браузера это submit и оно останавливается preventDefault. Если мы поставим stopPropagation, то submit пройдёт. Но остановиться работа других event listeners.
preventDefault
https://jsfiddle.net/ha0zt7c7/
stopPropagation
https://jsfiddle.net/bhruuems/